# 2 way sync function is not triggering when newly rows added from different google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, event-handling

I have created script that make 2 way sync between two seperat google spreadsheet and script is triggring onEdit, but my issue is that the script is not triggering when new data submitted to either of the sheet from other sources and it only trigger when I edit manually in either of sheets..

here is my scenario

Form sheet that submitt data to "Sheet1".
Sheet1 receive data from "Form Sheet".
Sheet2 receive data from "Sheet1" using two-way sync script.
any change or edit I make manually in sheet1 it applies on sheet2 and vice verse.

I know some people would say just use time-driven trigger or make the form sheet send data to both sheets, but these solutions not helping in my case.
here is my code:

````
function synctodestination() {
  var sourceSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sourceSheet = sourceSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var range = sourceSheet.getRange("A1:AD1500");
  var data = range.getValues();
  
  var destinationSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("11SayLZ1Bb1C3HxxxxxxxxxtvC7b4_EhW05GMvA");
  var destinationSheet = destinationSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var destinationRange = destinationSheet.getRange("A1:AD1500");
  destinationRange.setValues(data);
}```


I tried onChange trigger and did not work
````

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand the relationship between `Form sheet that submitt data to "Sheet1". Sheet1 receive data from "Form Sheet". Sheet2 receive data from "Sheet1" using two-way sync script. any change or edit I make manually in sheet1 it applies on sheet2 and vice verse.` and your showing script. Can I ask you the detail of your question? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: `on edit` and `on change` can only be triggered by manual input. Your options are only time-based or sending data to both sheets.

Comment: onChange changeType="OTHER" can trigger off of some imports

Comment: @Tanaike my question is there any solution to make my 2way sync script get triggered in "sheet1" whenever it receives new rows from "form sheet" "submitted via google app script"? unfortunately, the script only works when I make manual edits in the sheet myself not when it receives data from external sources. I don't want to use a time-driven trigger because that can cause issues if I make any edit in sheet2 that I will always edit through it and at the same time time-driven trigger executed.

Comment: @Cooper I tried changeType=OTHER but sadly didn't work